# websphere7 and JSF configuration

Tags: jsf, websphere

I worked JSF project in tomcast before, when I import my work to WEBsphere,(I create a empty  one, and copy the source),  in the beginning, it worked! I can see y interface display, all of libs and configuration files worked, but when I tried to run again,  I thought jsf-api, impl-api has conflicts, but run again, it will automatically deploy into workspace, so I delete them, and modify library deployment path, but it doesnot work until now!

It sucks me whole last week until now, I am not sure what is problem, later I can fix all error I can see in the project, but current issue is when I input "web/index.jsp" or "web/home.jsf" all of them display "webpage cannot display", but there is no error in cosole window, and even display /index.jsf has initialized. I used to doubt something wrong in web.xml, after I attempted to change it again and again, I found it seems like there is no error. I cannot understand why it worked before under same configuration environment, but now failed.

Below is my web.xml  and library list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>web</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>
        State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param> 
<param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name> 
<param-value>.jsf</param-value> 
</context-param> 


    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    <welcome-file>index.faces</welcome-file>

        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Lib:

```
activation-impl.jar
aspectjrt.jar
bootstrap.jar
bsf-engines.jar
cimgr.ops.jar
com.ibm.cds_.jar
com.ibm.events.client.jar
com.ibm.events.service.jar
com.ibm.ffdc.jar
com.ibm.icu.jar
com.ibm.isclite.migration.jar
com.ibm.jaxb.tools.jar
com.ibm.jaxws.tools.jar
com.ibm.sec.authz.ibmsecauthz_7.0.jar
com.ibm.uddi.jar
com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar
com.ibm.ws.admin.services.jar
com.ibm.ws.admin.system.jar
com.ibm.ws.amm.jar
 com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.jar
com.ibm.ws.cimgr.jar
com.ibm.ws.debug.osgi.jar
com.ibm.ws.eclipse.adaptors_7.0.0.jar
com.ibm.ws.ejbportable.jar
com.ibm.ws.emf.jar
com.ibm.ws.esi.jar
com.ibm.ws.jdt.core.jar
com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar
com.ibm.ws.mail.jar
com.ibm.ws.migration.jar
com.ibm.ws.policyset.migration.jar
com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.jar
com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.analysis.engine.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.commonj-twm.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.commons-collections.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.commons-discovery.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.commons-logging.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.db2.intf.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.javamail.jar
 com.ibm.ws.prereq.jrom.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.la.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.nativefile.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.olt.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.otis.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.ow.asm.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.rmm.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.rxa.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.syncml4j_2.6.0.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.toad.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.vajava.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.webtlsrn.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.wsdeploy.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.wsdl4j.jar
com.ibm.ws.prereq.xdi.jar
.ibm.ws.prereq.xlxp.jar
com.ibm.ws.proxy.admin.jar
com.ibm.ws.proxy.jar
com.ibm.ws.runtime.coregroupbridge.jar
com.ibm.ws.runtime.dist.jar
com.ibm.ws.runtime.gateway.jar
com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
com.ibm.ws.security.crypto.jar
com.ibm.ws.sib.server.jar
com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.sib.wccm.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.sip.container.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.sip.interface.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.sip.proxy.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.sip.quorum.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.wccm.cimgr.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.wccm.compatibility.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.wccm.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.webmsg.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.webservices.migration.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_7.0.0.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.webui.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.wlm.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.wsfp.main.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.wspolicy.main.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.wspolicy4j.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.wsspi.extension.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.wsspi.proxy.extension.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.wsspi.rrd.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.tivoli.pd.amwas.core_6.1.0.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.tivoli.pd.amwas.tai_6.1.0.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commandlineutils.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-discovery.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.1.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/databeans.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/EJBCommandTarget.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/el-api.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/el-ri.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/ffdcSupport.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/hmkbdv.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/hmkcom.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/hmkkan.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/hmkmbr.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/hmksec.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/htmlshell.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/installver.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/installxml.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/iscdeploy.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/ivblogbr.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/IVTClient.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/j2ee.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacl.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.annotation.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.compatibility.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.connector.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.deploy.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.ejb.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.interceptor.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.jacc.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.jaxr.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.jaxrpc.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.jms.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.jsf.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.jsp.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.jstl.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.jta.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.management.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.persistence.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.j2ee.servlet.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jNative2ascii.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jrom.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-api.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-nls.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/json-rpc-1.0.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsp-api.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/jstl.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/launchclient.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/lmproxy.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.6.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-impl.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/marshall.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-3.0.10.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/nif.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.axis2.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.myfaces1_2.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.ant.core.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.commands.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.contenttype.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.expressions.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.filesystem.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.jobs.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.resources.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.runtime_.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.variables.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.emf.common.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.emf.commonj.sdo.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.sdo.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.equinox.common_.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.equinox.registry.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.osgi_.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.text.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.update.configurator_.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/OTiSConvertTime.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/pc-appext.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/physicalrep.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/pmirm4arm.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/rrd-appext.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/rsadbutils.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/rsahelpers.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/serviceadapter.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/setup.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-struts.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/startup.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/tcljava.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/urlprotocols.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/wsatlib.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/wses_dynaedge.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war/WEB-INF/lib/wsif-compatb.jar
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/oplopiJSF/installedApps/w00376586Node02Cell/web.ear/web.war
```

Comment: oh god websphere.. this thing gives me nightmares. And all I tried was setting up a Lotus Connections test instance.

Comment: btw, jsp page can display, jsf not, when input jsf page to jsp suffic, definitely has error : cannot find facesContext".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have in your application web.ear two JSF implementations org.apache.myfaces.jar and another jsf-impl.jar.

You should define your JSF implementation that is not shipped within WAS with an isolated shared library. The approach is described in the WAS 7.0 help entry indicated below:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftweb_jsf.html